# How to make jQueryUI tooltip apply only on focus

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

How can I make the new JqueryUI tooltip visible only on `focus`: At the moment its on `focus` and on `hover`. I believe this is since JqueryUI 1.9

Comment: Wow such a simple question but I don't see a simple answer :(

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A bit shorter way:

`$(".selector").tooltip().off("mouseover mouseout");`

Comment: +1 this worked for what I needed, the opposite, wanted them on mouse only, not focus: $(element).tooltip().off("focusin focusout");

Comment: An add-on to the answer: `.off("mouseover mouseout");` will off all mouse over/out events. If you are using them, they will be unbind too. To make sure you are just doing `off` on the tooltip's ones, do like this: `$(".selector").tooltip(); var tooltipInstanceNamespace = $(".selector").tooltip("instance").eventNamespace; $(".selector").off('mouseover'+tooltipInstanceNamespace' mouseout'+tooltipInstanceNamespace);` This will off only the listeners with that tooltip instance namespace.

Answer (score 15):

This isn't ideal, but it should work:

```
$(".selector").tooltip({
    disabled: true
}).on("focusin", function () {
    $(this)
        .tooltip("enable")
        .tooltip("open");
}).on("focusout", function () {
    $(this)
        .tooltip("close")
        .tooltip("disable");
});
```

Basically, enable/open the tooltip on `focusin` and disable/close on `focusout`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/WmRuN/

Comment: I suspected something like this would be needed. Thanks.

Comment: Also. One problem I didn't think about with this, is that the browser inserts the standard titles on hover. :(